# Detect Vue page switching and run function accordingly

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, ionic-framework, vuejs3

### My problem

My app is composed of two major tabs, *Home* and *Map* and I use OpenLayers for that last. *Home* shows some details about a randomly chosen Feature on the map, and there is also a button that navigates to the map, **with focus on this specific Feature**.

The problem is that if I open the Map **before** clicking the button, it gets loaded with no particular focus (normal behavior) but then clicking the button in the *Home* tab won't focus the Feature, as the map has already been `setup` and `mounted`.

### What I tried

Here is my current code for the button, using query parameters:

```html
<!-- The button is actually a small map with a preview of the feature's location -->
<div id="mapContainer" @click="activateMap([discovery.lng, discovery.lat])"></div>
```

```js
activateMap() {
    const mapInstructions = {
        path: "/tabs/map/",
        query: {
            type: discovery.dType,
            id: discovery.id
        }
    };

    this.$router.push(mapInstructions);
}
```

And the component is getting the data this way:

```js
const route = useRoute();
const dType = route.query.dType.toString();
const id = route.query.id.toString();
if (dType && id) {
    const discovery = getDiscovery(parseInt(id), dType);
    this.focusDiscovery(discovery);
}
```

- I also tried watching `'$route'` but then if I click the button, the focus is made **every time**, while I only want to force the focus **when clicking the button**. **The reason is because the URI is not reset when opening the Map using my tabs toolbar, so it keeps all query params.**
- An alternative (but I couldn't find how to) would be to run a function with this last piece of code **every time the map is shown**, whatever the way (button or tabs navigation).

How can I solve this?

Comment: const dType = route.params.dType.toString;  // set the brackets   toString();

Comment: For you second bullet point, what about `onIonViewWillEnter` and kin?

Comment: What you seem to need is a selectedFeature state property in a store. If selectedFeature is populated, the map opens/goes to focusing that feature. If the feature is not populated, the map opens/goes to the default focus (probably zoomed out). This way it's the state that drives the behavior of your map, not the behavior of some other element in some other page/tab. If you want setting the selectedFeature to also change the URL, so the user can share a link to that feature, you can add it as a side-effect.

Comment: Set up a *runnable* [mcve] with what you have and I'll help. codesandbox.io makes [importing a local project](https://codesandbox.io/docs/learn/getting-started/your-first-sandbox#import-local-projects-via-cli) pretty easy.

Comment: What about running the focusing code in the map component in `onIonViewWillEnter`, and clearing the query params in `onIonViewWillLeave`?

Comment: Your `activateMap()` function is setting the query, but your component code is using the route params. Is this intentional?

Comment: @tao I thought about that but believed it wasn't the best fix to the problem. However, it seems to be the simplest solution to avoid changing the behavior of the whole app. I'll try that and come back to see. If this solution works, what should I do? Add the answer myself, credit your comment and mark it as accepted? Sorry I'm not used to SO guidelines for that case.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes no you're right it's not normal. It's code I forgot to change back when deciding to post on SO. I'll try to make it more consistent. I will also try your solution, thanks.

Comment: I'm just trying to help, I don't do it for reputation. If you find something that works post it as an answer, it might help others with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to `ionTabsWillChange` event in the component that contains the `<ion-tabs>` element and clean up the current parameters in the URL. Check the docs:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/tabs#events

In the template section of main component that contains the tabs:

```
<ion-tabs @ion-tabs-will-change="checkRoute">
...
</ion-tabs>
```

In the script section:

```
methods: {
  ionTabsWillChange(event) {
    if (event.tab === 'map') {
      this.$router.replace('/tabs/map');
    }
  }
```